# When to use schema.sql in spring boot app

Tags: java, sql, database, spring-boot, ddl

I am trying to understand when to use **schema.sql** db creation technique and when to rely on Spring boot's creation based on my entity classes. How to decide?

Comment: Never rely on creating the database through your entities. Always control the schema yourself, either by the `schema.sql` or by using something like Flyway to manage your schema. Don't rely on the ORM to do the proper thing for schema generation (anything besides a local test/poc).

Comment: Thanks for advice, can you clarify why I should never rely on creation by entities?

Answer (score 0):

Let's leave for the moment the `schema.sql` out.

ORM automatic schema creation (create or update or create-drop) is normally useful during the development of application. Even during release candidates and QA reviews it is still useful because the changes which happen from development team with issues arising could be live much faster.

When the application reaches a critical phase and is mature in production, then any changes happening automatically from ORM could be considered dangerous.

At this stage you would normally in big companies rollout in production database only some `sql` scripts that affect the database, which should be reviewed first and tested before rollout happens. Also a rollback `sql` might be necessary.

So normally ORM having effect in database schema is only during early stages of an application and not when it has matured enough in production.

Let's now come back to `schema.sql`. This file can be used just once to create the database from some `sql` commands. This also would not be expected to be run anytime the application executes. At least not in majority of applications.

I think a logical approach would be to use the ORM during intial stages of development and QA and then when you are about to reach a mature phase, you inspect what type of database the ORM has created and then you make a manual review just to be sure of everything and any optimizations which would make sense and at this stage you can create with the already existing schema of ORM your own permanent `schema.sql`.

The obvious reason for the above is that with `schema.sql` you have 100% control of how the database is created. Using ORM you depend on the ORM provider to build this for you. This ORM provider might provide some new library that affects how the previous was used and many other things. The result is that with ORM you  don't have 100% control on the database to be created.